# A number is triangular if and only if it is of the form $\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can prove the first part
from formula area of rectangle that it is $(n)(n+1)$ if  it triangle it is$\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$
But I can't prove  the backward part that is true 
Anyone have a hint ?

Comment: You can find the proof almost everywhere, e.g. [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/runsums/triNbProof.html).

Comment: [this might have an answer for you](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/elementary-number-theory-7th-edition-chapter-2.1-solutions-9780077418120)